# ZPL - How we can control width of ^BC (Code 128) bar code

Tags: zpl, code128

We are using Zebra Programming Language, ^BC (Code 128) bar code

currently using this command -

^XA
^FT230,140^BY2
^A0N,40,30
^BC,70,Y,N,N,A^FDABCDEFGH123456789012
^FS
^XZ

it is printing barcode too long. so please help me to control width of the barcode and how we centre aligned barcode also.

Answer (score 3):

Change `^BY2` to `^BY1` for width

`^FT230,140` defines the position being 230 dots from left and 140 from top, so to center, change 230 accordingly

Comment: Thanks, very helpful